# removing last 3 characters in custom JS Google Tag Manager variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to capture a string from a field, removing the last 4 characters (I want to capture the first part of a UK postcode, which can be 3 or 4 characters long).

I'm modifying a custom JS variable of Simo Ahava's. The starting point in this:

```
function() {
  var field = {{Form Element}}.querySelector('#inputFieldId');
  return field ? field.value : undefined;
}
```

I've been able to get the 1st 3 characters by doing this:

```
function() {
      var field = {{Form Element}}.querySelector('#postcode');
        var length = 3;
      return field ? field.value.substring (0, length) : undefined;
    }
```

but can't work out how to change it to just remove the last 3 characters.

I've tried

```
function() {
  var field = {{Form Element}}.querySelector('#postcode');
  return field ? field.value.substring (0, field.value.length-3) : undefined;
}
```

But that's not working. I'm a real beginner with JS so any help would be great!

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Your last variable should work if your `field` value is correct

```
function() {
   var field = {{Form Element}}.querySelector('#postcode');
   return field ? field.value.substring(0, field.value.length-3) : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
function() {
  var field = {{Form Element}}.querySelector('#postcode');
  return field ? field.value.substring(field.value.length-3) : undefined;
}
```